# elasticsearch 5.0 native plugin, query error

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, elasticsearch-5

I wrote a native plugin for es 5.0, which `extends Plugin implements ScriptPlugin`, and scripts `extends AbstractSearchScript`, installed ok, but when I execute the following query:

```
"script_score": {
    "script": {
      "id": "my_script_factory_name",
      "lang" : "native"
  }
}
```

It failed with the following error:

```
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"resource_not_found_exception","reason":"Unable to find script [native/my_script_factory_name] in cluster state"}],"type":"search_phase_execution_exception","reason":"all shards failed","phase":"query","grouped":true,
```

Comment: Have you restarted ES?

Comment: of course restarted...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the cause, the official 5.0 docs is the old version guide, the right query should use **inline**

```
"script_score": {
    "script": {
      "inline": "my_script_factory_name",
      "lang" : "native",
      "params": {
        ....
      }
  }
}
```